# Access to XMLHttpRequest at Spring Boot server blocked by CORS policy

Tags: java, cors, backend

I wrote an API in Spring Boot that takes parameters from a GET method and sends a response to the frontend, but when I send the data from the form with JQuery, the console of the browser explicitly says:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at '<backend path>' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I put  `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://127.0.0.1:5500", allowedHeaders = "*")`  on top of the REST Controller handling the request but it didn't work.

I also imported the security dependency and created a class WebSecurityConfig class that should manage the CORS of the project, but it actually doesn't work and gives me error in the return statement when i use the "antMatchers" method, it says that it can't resolve the method. Here's the code:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.HttpSecurityDsl;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;

import java.util.List;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));

        return http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults()).authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
    }
}
```